# Angular 5: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angular5

When I run my Angular 5 application with the command `ng serve --prod` the build phase succeed and I do not have any compilation errors.

As soon as I start the application I receive this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
        at t.peekStartsWith (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1553)
        at t.consumeOptional (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1563)
        at t.parseRootSegment (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1357)
        at t.parse (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1204)
        at t.applyRedirectCommands (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:2062)
        at t.expandRegularSegmentAgainstRouteUsingRedirect (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1937)
        at t.expandSegmentAgainstRouteUsingRedirect (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1887)
        at t.expandSegmentAgainstRoute (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1861)
        at e.project (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1798)
        at e._next (map.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:79)
        at t.peekStartsWith (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1553)
        at t.consumeOptional (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1563)
        at t.parseRootSegment (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1357)
        at t.parse (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1204)
        at t.applyRedirectCommands (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:2062)
        at t.expandRegularSegmentAgainstRouteUsingRedirect (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1937)
        at t.expandSegmentAgainstRouteUsingRedirect (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1887)
        at t.expandSegmentAgainstRoute (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1861)
        at e.project (router.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1798)
        at e._next (map.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:79)
        at D (zone.js:824)
        at D (zone.js:795)
        at zone.js:873
        at e.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:4724)
        at e.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
        at t.runTask (zone.js:192)
        at d (zone.js:602)
```

Someone knows what can cause this? The same application built not in production mode (i.e. `ng serve`) works flawlessly